# SchemaDisagreementException

Tags: cassandra

Trying to set up a cassandra cluster, but it tells me that I have a SchemaDisagreementException.  What is weird is that writing sometimes works, just not all of the time.  I assume that I must somewhere have different schemas, but I've cleared my data directories several times before, so it must not be in there.  Where else would my schema be declared, other than in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've inspired a FAQ entry! :)

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#schema_disagreement

(This didn't exist until 10 minutes ago, so no, you didn't miss it.)

Answer (score 0):

FAQ didn't helped me in getting this issue resolved, instead fuzzed me. I have document all my concerns and reasons of confusion at http://nsinfra.blogspot.in/2013/06/cassandra-schema-disagreement-problem.html

Anyways I got rid of this problem by synchronizing the clocks of cluster nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this too, about 1 in 3 times.

I'm able to reproduce it on a clean cluster -- no operations performed apart from starting the nodes -- and then listing schema versions confirms different some nodes already sometimes have different schemas.

I get the error even with just 2 nodes, seeds on both nodes set to the two nodes' IP addresses. Occurs starting concurrently or with a 2m delay before starting the second node.

This is Cassandra version 1.2.2. Times on the machines are in sync (<1s difference).

Comment: Cassandra 1.2.2 is buggy in this regard. Upping to 1.2.9 fixed the problem for me. Discussion on Cassandra mailing list today.